# postgresql-using trigger to fire

Tags: postgresql, triggers, database

I want to create a trigger so that whenever I make a change (Update or Delete) it should copy the old data to a new table (with same template).

I tried this code:

```
create table restrictions(ID int,name text);

insert into restrictions values(122,'suresh');

select * from restrictions;

create table restrictions_deleted(ID int,name text);// this is my duplicate table for keeping information of all updations.

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION moveDeleted() RETURNS trigger AS $$
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO restrictions_deleted VALUES(OLD.ID, OLD.name);
       RETURN OLD;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER moveDeleted
BEFORE DELETE ON restrictions 
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE moveDeleted();

delete from restrictions where ID=122;
select * from restrictions_deleted;
```

This code is capable of recording all the deleted data into duplicate table. But I want to do same for updates also.

Any suggestion, any idea?

Comment: And you're sure you want to _replicate a whole table_ on an update operation? Have you considered to use a data model which records the historic information you need to know?

Comment: @ClassStacker The current trigger wont replicate **whole** table. It will only cope the current row.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko Absolutely. My fault.

Comment: @ClassStacker Please let me know if there is some more effective alternative as you said above.

Comment: It really all depends on your requirements (plus the specific data model you have chosen for your solution) and your infrastructure. But as @IgorRomanchenko pointed out, I... erm... read your post too quickly before I made the above comment. Still, I often end up marking records as deleted or expired if I want historic information. Storage space, performance, and access to historic information are key factors for the decision.

Comment: could you please explain me as above query with a relevant example, it would be much helpful to understand the exact fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - in a trigger function you need to `RETURN NEW;` instead of `RETURN OLD;`.

Second - change the trigger to `BEFORE DELETE OR UPDATE`.

Last - it is better to have `AFTER DELETE OR UPDATE` for a logging trigger. This way it wont do useless work, when the change is rolled back.

BTW [`here`](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger) is a good example of logging/audit trigger.

UPDATE:

The function will look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION moveDeleted() RETURNS trigger AS $$
    BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
        INSERT INTO restrictions_deleted VALUES(OLD.ID, OLD.name);
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
        INSERT INTO restrictions_deleted VALUES(OLD.ID, OLD.name);
        RETURN OLD;
    END IF;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: i worked with this what you told, however i want both update and delete with the same trigger.kindly provide a suggestion

Comment: @user2160090 The `AFTER DELETE OR UPDATE` will work with both `UPDATE` and `DELETE`. Read the manual [`here`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html) for fusher information.

Comment: however i tried but not working for both,if using the code for update means we have to give NEW, for delete we have to give as OLD, how to give the both using trigger. please refer the code as given above function.

Comment: i tried it is working so good, thank you so much for the quick response